# Extracting information using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Hi I am new to using JSoap and html. I am currently trying to get information from a game stat website and having issues getting information between `<h1></h1>`.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://na.wildstats.gg/en/profile/60ae4f204a9aa2000f3d5f33").get();
Elements winRates = document.getElementsByClass("text-center m-0");
String html = winRates.text();


System.out.println(winRates);
System.out.println(html);
System.out.println("test");
```

output:

```
<h1 class="text-center m-0" id="battleStats_WinRate"></h1>
<h1 class="text-center m-0" id="battleStats_MVP"></h1>
<h1 class="text-center m-0" id="battleStats_Played"></h1>
test
```

On the website when I inspect it there is a percentage, number of MVPS and games played between the `<h1></h1>`, yet that is not showing up for me. I was wondering how I would get those numbers. I have been able to get the players ign and rank and level.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is for statics or very simple html sites.

Complex sites in the first http request download a basic or empty index.html and then using ajax, get the information from remote services like rest apis or microservices that returns json.

That's why, soups returns you that empty html.

### solution 1

Use another framework which uses a kind of browser in-memory. That kind of frameworks are capable of *wait* until the ajax gets the information and then your  will have the expected value:

- puppeteer.js
- casper.js
- sinon.js

### solution 2

If your only goal is to obtain the data, you could use the developer console of your favorite browser and identify the http service that returns your game data in json format.  After that, with a very simple http connection you will have the game data

### solution 3

Use selenium and a headless browser to get your data, waiting to the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work using JSoup and Regex named group to get the three types of battle Stats `allBattles`, `normalBattles`, `rankedBattles` with all attributes

```java
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://na.wildstats.gg/en/profile/60ae4f204a9aa2000f3d5f33").get();
Elements elements = document.select("script");
Pattern parserPattern = Pattern.compile("'(?<BATTLE>[a-zA-Z]+)': [{](?<ATTRIBUTES>[\n 'a-zA-Z0-9+:\"0-9a-zA-Z,.]+)[};]");
Matcher matcher = parserPattern.matcher(elements.toString());
while (matcher.find()) {
    String battleType = matcher.group("BATTLE");
    System.out.println("Battle Type: " + battleType);
    String[] attributesLines = matcher.group("ATTRIBUTES")
                    .replaceAll(",\n", "\n")
                    .split("\n");
    for (String line : attributesLines) {
        String[] keyValue = line.trim().split(":");
        if (keyValue.length != 2) continue;
        String key = keyValue[0];
        String value = keyValue[1];
        System.out.println("\t" + key + " : " + value);
    }
}
```

The output will be

[image]

You can then create a class for each battle with a name and map for attributes to represent the result and use them in UI

```java
public class Battle {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> attributes;

    ...
}
```